# How do I know all valid positions for a King to move on chess board without going to the opposite side

Tags: python-3.x, chess

So I have a chess board represented as an array of size 64 with top-left square being 0 and bottom-right square being 63. I have this function which gives all possible moves of King.

```
current_pos = i
arr = np.array([i-9, i-8, i-7, i-1, i+1, i+7, i+8, 1+9])
return arr

.
.
.

if selected position is in arr:
    move king
```

Where i is the number of the square on which king currently is.

This works if the king is not on edges of the chessboard.

BUT if king is on the bottom-right square, that is number 63, the function gives bottom-left square that is number 56 as a valid position for a king to move.

Is there any efficient way to know that the king is going to the other edge and is not a valid move?

I'm having same problems with almost all my pieces where the function will allow piece to go on the other side of board but i figured king's movement was the simplest to ask.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a single length 64 list for positions rather than an 8x8 list of lists or numpy array?

Comment: *"I have this function"* perhaps you might include it so we can see it and give suggestions...

Comment: @JonSG first 3 lines is the function I and it returns all valid moves of king. and below is the pseudo code that see if the move is valid

Comment: Also, I was thinking of changing the board representation and use (x, y) co-ordinates because I learned a little late that representing board as numbers array is not beneficial. I just wanted to see if there is a way to solve this which I wasn't thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 1D list is way faster than a 2D 8x8 list so I like that you are using this approach.

The way this is handled is to use a 10x12 board where you have an extra 2 rows on bottom and top, and an extra column on the left and right:

[image]

Then in your generate move function you simple check if the square you are looking at is within the board. If it is not, you skip to the next square in your loop.

Please read more about it on https://www.chessprogramming.org/10x12_Board. It is also a great site for information about chess programming in general.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using table lookup.

##### Code

```
piece_offsets = {
    'n': [-17, -15, -10, -6, 6, 10, 15, 17],
    'b': [ -9,  -7,  9, 7],
    'r': [ -8,  -1,  8, 1],
    'q': [ -9,  -8, -7, -1, 9,  8,  7,  1],
    'k': [ -9,  -8, -7, -1, 9,  8,  7,  1]
}

sqdist = [[0 for x in range(64)] for y in range(64)]

pseudo_legal = {    
    'n': [[] for y in range(64)],
    'b': [[] for y in range(64)],
    'r': [[] for y in range(64)],    
    'q': [[] for y in range(64)],
    'k': [[] for y in range(64)],
}


def distance(sq1, sq2):
   file1 = sq1 & 7
   file2 = sq2 & 7
   rank1 = sq1 >> 3
   rank2 = sq2 >> 3
   rank_distance = abs(rank2 - rank1)
   file_distance = abs(file2 - file1)
   return max(rank_distance, file_distance)


def print_board():
    for i in range(64):
        print(f'{i:02d} ', end='')
        if (i+1)%8 == 0:
            print()


def on_board(s):
    return s >= 0 and s < 64


def init_board():    
    for sq1 in range(64):
        for sq2 in range(64):
            sqdist[sq1][sq2] = distance(sq1, sq2)
            
    for pt in ['n', 'b', 'r', 'q', 'k']:
        for s in range(64):
            for offset in piece_offsets[pt]:
                to = s + offset
                if pt in ['k', 'n']:
                    if on_board(to) and sqdist[s][to] < 4:
                        pseudo_legal[pt][s].append(to)
                else:  # sliders
                    s1 = s
                    while True:
                        to1 = s1 + offset
                        if on_board(to1) and sqdist[s1][to1] < 4:
                            pseudo_legal[pt][s].append(to1)
                            s1 = to1
                        else:
                            break


def main():
    init_board()  # build sqdist and pseudo_legal_to tables
    
    print_board()
    print()  
    
    for pt in ['n', 'b', 'r', 'q', 'k']:
        for s in [0, 63, 36]:
            print(f'pt: {pt}, from: {s}: to: {pseudo_legal[pt][s]}')
        print()
        
    # pseudo_legal_sq = pseudo_legal['b'][61]
    # print(pseudo_legal_sq)
    
    
main()
```

##### Output

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 

pt: n, from: 0: to: [10, 17]
pt: n, from: 63: to: [46, 53]
pt: n, from: 36: to: [19, 21, 26, 30, 42, 46, 51, 53]

pt: b, from: 0: to: [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63]
pt: b, from: 63: to: [54, 45, 36, 27, 18, 9, 0]
pt: b, from: 36: to: [27, 18, 9, 0, 29, 22, 15, 45, 54, 63, 43, 50, 57]

pt: r, from: 0: to: [8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
pt: r, from: 63: to: [55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56]
pt: r, from: 36: to: [28, 20, 12, 4, 35, 34, 33, 32, 44, 52, 60, 37, 38, 39]

pt: q, from: 0: to: [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
pt: q, from: 63: to: [54, 45, 36, 27, 18, 9, 0, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56]
pt: q, from: 36: to: [27, 18, 9, 0, 28, 20, 12, 4, 29, 22, 15, 35, 34, 33, 32, 45, 54, 63, 44, 52, 60, 43, 50, 57, 37, 38, 39]

pt: k, from: 0: to: [9, 8, 1]
pt: k, from: 63: to: [54, 55, 62]
pt: k, from: 36: to: [27, 28, 29, 35, 45, 44, 43, 37]
```